# Implement a Cashback Mechanism in ecommerce

Tags: amazon-product-api, paytm

Here is the use case.Say I am an associate of amazon e-commerce and earn x% money for each sale of a product happening from my site.Now I want to implement a cashback mechanism such that for every product sold in amazon with my associate tag I give x/2% of the fee as a cashback to my customer.I have no idea as to how to go about solving this problem.

Here is the problem I am facing:

After every successful transaction I need an Amazon API which pings me so that I put the cash to my user's paytm wallet or something.
But I don't see the availability of any such API or maybe I am getting the whole flow wrong.

Could any of you guide me on the right track?

Comment: I've the same use case.. did you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The process you are looking for is known as customer gratification process. If you are working in NodeJS then you can take help of [paytmGratify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paytmGratify) or [paytmgratify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paytmgratify)